# What is the purpose with files ending with *CS.cs in Xamarin Forms projects?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning myself some Xamarin development. When I study examples of Xamarin projects, [like this one](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/LoginFlow/LoginNavigation), I sometimes see that a page has a mysterious file with the same name as the xaml file and its code-behind file, but ending with `*CS.cs` as you can see is the case with the LoginPage in the above linked project:

- LoginPage.xaml
- LoginPage.xaml.cs
- LoginPageCS.cs     <--- What is this?

`LoginPage.xaml` is of course the xaml description of the layout and `LoginPage.xaml.cs` is the code-behind. But what does `LoginPageCS.cs`? I can remove it from the project and rerun the solution with the same functionality as before. So what is the purpose with files ending with `*CS.cs`? I have seen several sample projects where there are `*CS.cs` files.

Comment: The margin is just a visual way to tell that the page is created via C# code and not Xaml.

Comment: XAML is friendly to a UI designer and is input for a *code generator*.  You cannot normally see the code it generates and that code is not very pretty.  So as an alternative, they also provide the fooCS.cs file that does the exact same thing that the foo.xaml and foo.xaml.cs files do.  But in another class named fooCS.  That class is not actually used in the project.  Beyond the demonstrative use, it might inspire a programmer to write code instead of xaml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code, LoginPageCS.cs appears to be largely identical to LoginPage.xaml - so would be a way to create the page controls in C# as opposed to XAML. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830770/benefits-of-xaml-over-c-sharp-or-vice-versa-in-xamarin-forms) for a discussion on the difference.

Note the similarities

LoginPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="LoginNavigation.LoginPage" Title="Login">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Sign Up" Clicked="OnSignUpButtonClicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Username" />
            <Entry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="username" />
            <Label Text="Password" />
            <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" IsPassword="true" />
            <Button Text="Login" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" />
            <Label x:Name="messageLabel" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

LoginPageCS.cs:

```
public LoginPageCS ()
{
    var toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem {
        Text = "Sign Up"
    };
    toolbarItem.Clicked += OnSignUpButtonClicked;
    ToolbarItems.Add (toolbarItem);

    messageLabel = new Label ();
    usernameEntry = new Entry {
        Placeholder = "username"    
    };
    passwordEntry = new Entry {
        IsPassword = true
    };
    var loginButton = new Button {
        Text = "Login"
    };
    loginButton.Clicked += OnLoginButtonClicked;

    Title = "Login";
    Content = new StackLayout { 
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
        Children = {
            new Label { Text = "Username" },
            usernameEntry,
            new Label { Text = "Password" },
            passwordEntry,
            loginButton,
            messageLabel
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Oh ok! So the sample project just provides two ways of how to make the design - one by using XAML and the other one by using code? :-)

Comment: It would appear so